# Opposite of backspace?

Tags: terminal, ascii

Is there a ASCII character that does the 'opposite' of backspace, i.e., that moves the cursor one position *forward*? Id like a character X such that

```
print("bad\rXbc")
```

prints `bcd` (the example is python, but this should be rather a subject depending on the terminal emulator). X cannot be a white space, for the white space overwrites:

```
print("bad\r bc")
```

prints  `cd`. In princible, `\t` does what I want, but the sought character should move by only one character forward. Does it exist?

Edit. To make my question clear: the BS does not delete printed characters, in the sense that they are still visible unless overwritten. Of course this depends on the terminal emulator. For the macOS terminal, this is the case:

[image]

Comment: The opposite of *back*space is space. But that's not quite what you are looking for.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Well, BS doesn't overwrite the character under it by itself, issuing repeated BS leaves the existing text visible in virtually all terminal emulators, which is not what white space does.

Comment: I would have ventured to say that close to all terminal emulators do delete existing text on backspace.

Comment: Is there a specific language/technology you have in mind? Languages support different libraries and even terminals/emulators support different protocols.

Comment: [`tput`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tput.1.html) has capabilities like what you're asking for.

Comment: I found that the escape sequence `\033[D` for the right arrow key does the job, at least on the emulators I've lying around to try.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: I think that's not the case; many or most go back and just overwrite when you print another character.

Comment: I have used Gnome terminal, xterm, iTerm2, macOS terminal, and the Windows terminal for WSL, and they all delete characters on backspace

Comment: @ macOS terminal doesn't delete on BS. See edited post.